# why are my media queries not working on bootstrap?

Tags: css, media-queries

new to Bootstrap. I'm looking to increase nav font size for larger screens (iPad and up), but my media queries don't seem to be working.

```css
// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    
    .nav-link {
            font-size: 50px; 
            margin-left: 1.5%;}
    

}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About </a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="berlin.html">Berlin </a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="los-angeles.html">LA</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because `//` is not a valid comment in CSS and it breaks the `@media` immediately following:

`/* Only this comment is valid in CSS */`:

```css
/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"></a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About </a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="berlin.html">Berlin </a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="los-angeles.html">LA</a>
</nav>
```

Obviously, it has nothing to do with Bootstrap. Note pre-processors (such as LESS or SASS) parse `//` correctly, commenting the entire line (they basically turn it into a one line `/* comment */` in the CSS output).